# Initialize custom c# control depending on new custom property on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a new Custom Button and a new Boolean property.
The design features works good when i add the new custom button to my Form in Visual Studio .

I want to load two designs depending on that boolean property but the Parent forms already has the design code in formdesigner.cs and the button looks the same.

What method should i override to access the "Load" of the Button?

**This is my button cs**

```
     namespace Regio.UI
      {
public class MetroButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public bool Highlight { get; set; }
    public MetroButton()
    {
        if (Highlight == true)
        {


            base.BackColor = Color.White;
            base.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        }
        else {
            base.BackColor = Color.White;
            base.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            base.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            base.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 174, 219);
            base.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
            base.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

        }
    }

}
 }
```

This is the Form1.Designer.cs:

```
 this.metroButton1 = new Regio.UI.MetroButton();
        this.metroButton2 = new Regio.UI.MetroButton();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // metroButton1
        // 
        this.metroButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.metroButton1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        this.metroButton1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.metroButton1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.metroButton1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.metroButton1.Highlight = false;
        this.metroButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(212, 172);
        this.metroButton1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        this.metroButton1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.metroButton1.Name = "metroButton1";
        this.metroButton1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.metroButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(171, 111);
        this.metroButton1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.metroButton1.Text = "metroButton1";
        this.metroButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, Visual Studio can be annoying presumptuous when it comes to custom controls. But your code does have a flaw. You've put inside your constructor that when the boolean is true, it is designed one way, and when it is false, it is designed abother. However, I imagine that you'd want the design to be reset when the boolean is changed. Here's how I would change this.

```
public class MetroButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    private bool highlight;
    public bool Highlight
    { 
        get
        {
            return highlight;
        }
        set
        {
            highlight = value;
            if (highlight)//This is the same as "if(highlight == true)" but the last part is redundant in most programming languages.
            {

                FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
                FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
                FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            }
            else 
            {
                base.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 174, 219);
                base.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 3;
                base.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            }
        }
    }
    public MetroButton()
    {
        base.BackColor = Color.White;
        base.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        Highlight = true;//Just setting a default.
    }

}
```

Now, whenever the value of "Highlight" is changed, the code within your if statements will be run.